# Pull to refresh gesture in flutter material

Tags: dart, flutter, gesture

I want to detect when user want to refresh page in a flutter app .
for that i want to know when user swipe up on top of page by force then call a function to refresh data like most of the material app UX of pull to refresh gesture.
  anyone know how to implement it in a scaffold widget like below:

```
return new Scaffold(
         appBar: new AppBar(
           title: new Text('title'),
         ),
         body: new ListView(
            //mylist
         ),
         onPullToRefresh:this.myEventHandlerFunction
      )
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/overscroll_demo.dart fromhttps://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1595#issuecomment-373620009